# Why do I extract too many spurious branchpoints (and end points) from a binarized skeleton using bwmorph in matlab?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, feature-extraction, mathematical-morphology

I am trying to extract feature points from a binarised skeleton. I have the binary skeleton image.
[binary vessel pattern](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwKuB.png)

I used bwmorph(BW,'thin'), bwmorph(BW,'branchpoints'), bwmorph(BW,'endpoints') to extract feature points. What I obtain is too many false fature points.
[What I extracted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXLpW.png)

Here is the code that I used.

```
BW= imread('ExtractedVesselZ002.png');

figure; imshow(BW);

hold all;

BW= bwmorph(BW,'thin');

B = bwmorph(BW,'branchpoints');

[y,x] = find(B);

plot(x,y,'ro');



B1 = bwmorph(BW,'endpoints');

[y,x] = find(B1); 
plot(x,y,'go');
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I would appreciate any helps.

Comment: We'd need a `png` (not a jpg, its compressed) to test this, but have you considered avoiding using `BW= bwmorph(BW,'thin')`? the right way of skeletonizing is supposed to be `BW= bwmorph(BW,'skel')`

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the comment. 

I edited the formats.
"ExtractedVesselZ002.png" is already a skeletonised image. I am trying to replicate the results of a paper which used BCOSFIRE to extract skeletons, and then from the skeleton it extracts the feature points. I used BCOSFIRE code to extract the skeletons from my images. 

To make sure, I tried using bwmorph(BW,'skel'). I still get too many fake feature points.

Comment: From the docs: “To find branch points, the image must be skeletonized. To create a skeletonized image, use bwmorph(BW,'skel').”

Comment: @CrisLuengo Hi. Thanks for the comment. My images are already skeletonised.

Comment: I said that because your code does `bwmorph(BW,'thin')`, which is not a skeletonization. The branch points and end points algorithms have certain expectations of the input image that are apparently not satisfied in your image.

Comment: Is `BW` even binary? Does `unique(BW)` return the array [0,1]? How could it, after applying `rgb2gray`? Try `BW = BW > 0` before calling the `bwmorph` functions.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thanks. That’s right. I shouldn't have used rgb2gray function.

Comment: The problem is not the `rgb2gray` function, it is that you don't make the image binary after that. You need a binary image, which results from a thresholding step (i.e. a logical comparison). As I said: **"Try `BW = BW > 0` before calling the `bwmorph` functions."**